# Change input style if empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the color of the input border if it is empty when submitting the form. My attempt:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $form = $('form[name="f_cadastrofinan"]');

  $form.submit(function() {
    var confOs = $('input[name="os"]').val();
    var confData = $('input[name="data"]').val();
    var confTech = $('input[name="tech"]').val();
    var confDescri = $('input[name="descri"]').val();
    var confPag = $('input[name="pag"]').val();
    var confValor = $('input[name="valor"]').val();

    if (confOs == "" || confData == "" || confTech == "" || confDescri == "" || confPag == "" || confValor == "") { //detect empty
      alert('preencha os campos: '); //how to list empty inputs?
      $('input[type="text"]').is(':empty').css('border', '1px solid red'); //change border input
    } else {
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
      }, 'json');
      alert('inserido com sucesso!');
    }

    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your console. It will contain an error. This is because `is()` returns a boolean, not a jQuery object, so you cannot chain another jQuery method call from it.

In addition, as pointed out by @Roy in the comments, `:empty` looks at the nodes within an element. As such it does not work on the `value` of `input` elements.

To address this use `filter()` instead:

```
$('input[type="text"]').filter((i, e) => e.value.trim().length === 0).css('border', '1px solid red');
```

Even better than that, add a class to the element instead of embedding CSS within your JS:

```
$('input[type="text"]').filter((i, e) => e.value.trim().length === 0).addClass('error');
```

Comment: I think that `:empty` doesn't work for `input values`: Check https://jsfiddle.net/9f1xrde4/

Answer (score 1):

Check `val().length` like below:

```js
$('input[type="text"]').val().length <= 0 ? $('input[type="text"]').css('border', '1px solid red') : null
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Also there is a alternate pure `CSS` way:

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" required>
```